# rails migration is not reflecting while migration is successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created 2 tables (`categories` and `products`) and I did `has_many` association like `Category has_many :products` and `Product belongs_to :category`.

When I do a migration like:

```
rails generate migration add_product_id_to_categories product_id:integer
```

then migration is running but not seeing `product_id` in `Category`.

I've tried multiple ways like

```
add_product_id_to_category product_id:integer
```

but still facing the same problem.

Comment: What is in the migration file?

Comment: As the command implies, `rails generate migration` generates the migration. It does not run it. Open the generated migration, check to see if it looks good, then run it using `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: has your migration successfully run?

Answer (score 5):

You only generated a migration file (`rails generate migration add_product_id_to_categories product_id:integer`). You have to run the migration with `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

Generating a migration is a different thing than actually running it. You just generated it, and in order to execute what you have written, you need to run it, and you can do so by invoking the following command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Not sure that either you have run the migration or not, run the following command, and it will tell you the statues of all the migrations. If the status is `up`, the migration has been run, and for `down`, a migration couldn't be run.

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

When you run a migration, and you would like to get notified in terminal that it has been successfully run, you can add a `puts` statement in there like following:

```
class AddColumnToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :categories, :product_id, :integer, index: true
    puts "product_id column has been added into categories."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `rails generate migration AddProductIdToCategories product_id:integer`?

When you have created the migration if you look inside the migration file you can see if any code has been generated in the change method before you run the migration. If it has not generated any content you can manually add it:

```
def change
    add_column :categories, :product_id, :integer
end
```